# Can anyone help me in my MYSQL Query for many to many

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: Products, Inventory and Ingredients

```
Product Table    
ID[PK]        Name            Type
1         OrdinaryBurger     Burger
2         CheeseBurger       Burger
```

---

```
Inventory table
ID[PK]    Item_name    Stocks
100       Buns         5
101       Patties      5
103       Cheese       0
```

---

```
Ingredients table
ID[PK]      ProductID[FK]    InventoryID[FK]  Quantity
1001        1                  100            1
1002        1                  101            1
1003        2                  100            1
1004        2                  101            1
1005        2                  103            1
```

I want to create a query that can show all the products with how many it can make for example:

```
Products table

Product_name      Number_of_item_it_can_make     
OrdinaryBurger     5
CheeseBurger       0
```

I don't know how to start. thank you for the help.

Comment: You also need to explain how those results are supposed to be calculated. I'm guessing it's the maximum of stocks for all the ingredients in the product? Or maybe it's the maximum of `stocks/quantity`?

Comment: You start by learning about SQL `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`. [so] is not a programming school, you're expected to learn the basics first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd query the minimum of the ingredients in the inventory divided by the ingredients required to produce it, per product:

```
SELECT   p.name, FLOOR(MIN(inv.stocks / ing.quantitiy)) AS num_can_make
FROM     product p
JOIN     ingredients ing ON p.id = ing.productId
JOIN     inventory inv ON ing.inventoryId = inv.id
GROUP BY p.name
```